# Call a virtual method from its overridden

Tags: c#, polymorphism, virtual

In order to call the base virtual method from its overridden one, how should I define the instance?

Assume I have class Derived which extends Base class. I have a virtual method in Base which is overrided in class Derived.

Like this :  `Base instance = new Derived();`

or like this:  `Derived instance = new Derived();`

For sure I shall not use `Base instance = new Based();` for it call the virtual methos and not its override.

Comment: Your goal is a bit confusing: "call the base virtual method from its overridden one". Say we're talking about method `X`. Is `X` defined on `Base`? Did `Derived` override it? If so, is the the overriden method calling the base implementation (i.e., `base.X();`)?

Comment: Both examples will execute an overriden method

Comment: Unless I'm interpreting your question incorrectly: you can't.

Comment: Afaik C# is using a vtable mechanismus, this means that the typ of the variable doesnt matter. You cannot call the base method from outside.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel, Why not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether a method override calls the implementation of the base class does not depend on the type of variable you use. So, as soon as you add `base.MethodName()` to the implementation of the override, the first two ways you describe will be ok.

As you also mention, the third approach will not work as it does not call the overridden version of the method.

Comment: Thanks. You mean there is no difference at all between 2 first option?

Comment: @user3165438: no, not in terms of whether the base implementation will be called or not. That depends solely on the method body.

Comment: Misunderstood, Can you clarify please?

Comment: @user3165438: if you override a virtual method and you include the call to the base implementation, the 1st and 2nd approach will both call the base implementation. If you don't include the call, neither of them will call the base implementation.

Comment: Again, no difference at all between 2 options?

Comment: @user3165438: no difference. As the method is virtual, both ways call the overridden version of the method. If that overridden version contains a call to the base implementation, this call will be executed (as any other instruction). It does not depend on the type of variable you use to access the instance.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a grotty way you can do that. You'll have to expose a method which calls base version. IMO don't do that. but... It is possible.

```
void Main()
{
    B b = new B();
    b.DoSomething();
    b.CallAVersionDoSomething();
}

class A 
{
    public virtual void DoSomething()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("A DoSomething");
    }
}

class B : A 
{
    public override void DoSomething()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("B DoSomething");
    }

    public virtual void CallAVersionDoSomething()
    {
        base.DoSomething();
    }
}
```

Or if you want to expose it really you can expose another method in `Base class` which does the job for you. Here's how you go

```
class A 
{
    public virtual void DoSomething()
    {
        ActualDoSomething();
    }

    public void ActualDoSomething()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("A DoSomething");
    }
}

class B : A 
{
    public override void DoSomething()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("B DoSomething");
    }    
}
```

and you can use `instance.ActualDoSomething()` which can't be overridden so you get base class version all the time.